# Acess element in a nested table

Tags: jquery

Im basically trying to print policy when any of the child elements are clicked.
It's a really weird list that I got and I am trying to get it to work but cannot get it to display.

```
 $(".submenu li").click(function() {

 alert($(this).text()); 
 alert( $(this).parent().find('li.sub').text());

 });
```

i tried

```
     alert( $(this).parent().find('li.sub').text());
     alert($(this).closest('.submenu').closest('a').text());

     alert($(this).closest('.submenu').closest('sub').find("a").text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ettnxuxa/

Expected output after clicking any child element:
its alerts just "policy"

Comment: could you mention what exactly should happen, maybe write down a sample action and expected output.

Comment: I don't believe 'closest' does what you expect it to, it only traverses up the DOM tree:
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: im trying to print just "policy" after clicking any child element. @Iceman

Comment: u mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/alokrajiv/ettnxuxa/4/

Comment: not hard coded.. just some way to traverse the dom for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parent()` method only gives you the immediate parent element. To do what you'd like to do, try:

`alert($(this).parent().parent('.sub').text());`

Better though, would be to use:

`alert($(this).closest('.sub').text());`

To get a child element of `.sub` you would then use the `children()` method, so:

`alert($(this).closest('.sub').children('a').text());`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ettnxuxa/3/)

Comment: is it possible to just print out "policy"